# Removing contents of existing div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that gets data back from php and if it receives "unauthorized", it's supposed to show a modal explaining the possible error AND remove any content from the div. It basically does this, but the code still remains, so someone could just look at the source and read what's there.

`#main_content` starts out as `display:hidden`, so I wouldn't think it would appear at all with the code I have.

```
function callCharts() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'all_data.php',
        type: 'GET',     
        success: function(data) {
            var check = data;

            if (check =='unauthorized') {
                $('#main_content').remove();
                // also have tried .empty and .html("")
                $('#unauthorized_modal').modal('show');
            }
            else {
                $('#main_content').css("display","inherit");
                console.log("authorized");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Relevant HTML

```
 <div id="main_content" style="display:none;">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="block-flat" style="margin-bottom:10px; ">
        <div class="header">
          <h3 style="display:inline;">Data Overview</h3>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant HMTL as well?

Comment: Modifying the DOM does not affect the source code.

Comment: try hide the #main_content on initialization, and display when authorized

Comment: @RickHitchcock I guess I knew this, but I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: @imnancysun That's what I have. Check out the HTML that I just added.

Comment: If your goal is to hide source code from unauthorized users, you'll have to do that on the PHP side.

Comment: sorry, im a bit confused as to what you're trying to achieve. are you trying to get the div `#main_conent` to not show if `data == "unauthorized"` or to rip `#main_content` from the dom? when you say "but the code still remains" what do you mean?

Comment: @indubitablee rip from the dom...code remains meaning if you view source, you can see everything in the hidden div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your ajax function within this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    callCharts();
});
```